# displayform: Show columns from multiple list joined on ID as key

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I want to display a list item with columns from other lists also joined on a id column as a key.

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand but may be you are looking for lookup columns,

[lookup column in sahrepoint](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiN6a2n6NfKAhUI6aYKHUwrA3oQtwIINzAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DShLH0mBcA54&usg=AFQjCNE_jJV2B_B875PpAw113BhTtwQUeQ&sig2=2iuToizeubvEUWcM4tXfEA&bvm=bv.113034660,d.dGY)